# How do I fix this so that the error goes away on Brackey's unity tutorial?

Tags: c#

I'm following a brackeys tutorial and getting the Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected error message. Here's my code.

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody Rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            Rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            Rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);



        }
        if (Rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<Manager>().GameOver();

        }


    }
  }
}
```

I tried deleting and rewriting it entirely.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the **complete, exact** error message instead of paraphrasing it. It's on the screen right in front of you, so there's no excuse for not including it in your question. While you're making that edit, you can also add a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, because it could be in other code that you've not included here.

Comment: Remove the last `}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.